# onClick not working in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function Navbar() {

    const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
    if (isDark) {
        let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        body.classList.add("dark");
        let darkIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("dark-icon")[0];
        darkIcon.style.display = "none";
        
    } else {
        let lightIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("light-icon")[0];
        lightIcon.style.display = "none";
        
    }
   }, [isDark])

    

    return (
        <div class="navbar">
        
        <h1>devfinder</h1>
        <div className="toggle">
        <p onClick={() => {
            setIsDark(!isDark);
        }}className="light-icon">Light <img src={sunIcon} alt="Sun"/> </p>
        <p onClick={() => {
            setIsDark(!isDark);
        }} className="dark-icon">Dark  <img src={moonIcon} alt="Moon"/></p>
        
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

The onClick functions that I have in my paragraph tags aren't working and I have no clue why. There are no errors in the console, the function is just never called. Any suggestions?

*** EDIT ***
The issue with my onClick functions not firing had to do with positioning. The "toggle" div that the functions are in were set to float right. I had to relatively position the element and then add a z-index to it in order to be able to click on it.

Comment: If you're using React, don't use native DOM methods...

Comment: why are you using a function inside the parentheses for onclick? simply keep it  `onClick={setIsDark(!isDark)}`. And if there is any error, there should be some error message in the terminal as well. Are you sure there is none?

Comment: @CodeFingers Event listeners need to be assigned _references_ to functions that they can call. `setIsDark(setIsDark(!isDark))` assigns the result of _calling_ the function. OP has the correct approach.

Comment: You should avoid using DOM elements, however, this has been a little too over-engineered : you can simply use `setIsDark(false)` for the light icon, and `setIsDark(true)` for the dark icon

Comment: Yea @Andy that's a refresher. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

In React, it is incorrect to use DOM methods. React handles everything for you. Here is your code refactored a bit to likely do what you want it to:

```js
import moonIcon from 'some/directory'
import sunIcon from 'some/directory'

function Navbar() {

    const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false);
    const [text, setText] = useState("Light")
    const [iconClass, setIconClass] = useState("light-icon")
    const [icon, setIcon] = useState(sunIcon)
    const darkIcon = ( <img src={moonIcon} alt="Moon"/> )
    const lightIcon = ( <img src={sunIcon} alt="Sun"/> )

   useEffect(() => {
    if (isDark) {
        setIcon(moonIcon)
        setText("Dark")
        setIconClass("dark-icon")
    } else {
      setIcon(sunIcon)
      setText("Light")
      setIconClass("light-icon")
    }
   }, [isDark])

    

    return (
        <div class="navbar">
          <h1>devfinder</h1>
          <div className="toggle">
            <p className={iconClass} onClick={() => { setIsDark(!isDark)}}>
                 {text}{icon}
            </p>       
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Breaking this code down is important because it changes a lot about your approach and makes it more of a "React" approach by using the `useState` hook to store the state of several different elements.

```js
const [text, setText] = useState("Light")
const [iconClass, setIconClass] = useState("light-icon")
const [icon, setIcon] = useState(sunIcon)
```

We can store the state of text, class names, and even which icon to display. `useState` is very powerful!

```js
const darkIcon = ( <img src={moonIcon} alt="Moon"/> )
const lightIcon = ( <img src={sunIcon} alt="Sun"/> )
```

You can also store html code as a constant using jsx, you aren't limited to just returning it. This means we can pass html code around as a variable!

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (isDark) {
        setIcon(moonIcon)
        setText("Dark")
        setIconClass("dark-icon")
    } else {
      setIcon(sunIcon)
      setText("Light")
      setIconClass("light-icon")
    }
   }, [isDark])
```

The `useEffect` section just replaces your DOM methods with state updates. How does it work?

```js
<p className={iconClass} onClick={() => { setIsDark(!isDark)}}>
  {text}{icon}
</p>
```

Notice how in your returned html, I've reduced your paragraphs down from two just to one. That's because instead of having two paragraphs that conditionally set their `display` css, you can actually just have one paragraph that conditionally displays *html elements and images*!

`useEffect` in React will run code within it once per frame. So what it's doing is checking if the state `isDark` has changed (via onClick). If it has, then perform some update. The updates: set the icon (to either moon or sun), set the text (the text next to the icon, either "Light" or "Dark"), and set the class of the paragraph (because I noticed that class changes based on dark vs light mode).

Referring back to the paragraph: you can pass your JavaScript variables into your html if you wrap them with curly braces (`className={iconClass}` will set the className to whatever `iconClass`'s value is, etc.).

When you click the paragraph, the variables update, and the html will also update to have the new values.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to switch between light and dark mode here is my simple illustration for that to get a basic idea for you

```
export default function App() {
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="navbar">
        <h1>devfinder</h1>
        <h4>color mode is {!dark ? "light" : "dark"}</h4>
        <div className="toggle">
          <div onClick={() => setDark(false)} className="light-icon">
            Light
            <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
          </div>
          <div onClick={() => setDark(true)} className="dark-icon">
            Dark
            <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this switch state and you can do whatever you want with  state
working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-framework-rsgue

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to toggle between dark and light remove the unnecessary `useEffect` (don't use native DOM methods with React), and use a ternary operator in your `return` to determine which paragraph/icon should be used when the component re-renders when the state changes.

Note: I've used font-awesome here because I don't have access to your images.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div class="navbar">
      <h1>devfinder</h1>
      <div className="toggle">
        {isDark ? (
          <p
            onClick={() => setIsDark(!isDark)}
            className="dark"
          >Dark&nbsp;
            <i className="fa-solid fa-moon"></i>
          </p>
        ) : (
          <p
            onClick={() => setIsDark(!isDark)}
            className="light"
          >Light&nbsp;
            <i class="fa-solid fa-sun"></i>
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
p { padding: 5px 0 5px 5px; } 
p:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.light { background-color: #FAFAD2; color: black; }
.dark { background-color: #333333; color: white; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```